# What distinguishes 恩, 義務, 義理 and 人情 from each other?

Tags: words

I have an idea about the basics, but I'm fuzzy on the details, and it's been awhile since I've studied the subject in depth. Anyone have some answers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

恩 - favor or kindness from others that one should be feeling a sense of gratitude toward

義務 - duty rooted in social systems, usually associated with legal senses, such as liability or military service

義理 - duty rooted in personal relations usually friendship. family relations never or rarely come in this category.

人情 - pity or sympathy one feels when facing someone else's undeserved accident/accusation

**Note**

義理がある/ない - describes a person or people or their relation's being or not being observing such duties

> かれは義理がある He is a faithful person.
>   かれは義理がない He is a unreliable person.

人情がある/ない - similar to 義理, describing subject's property.

> かれは人情がある He is easily moved by compassion.
>   かれは人情がない He is cold-hearted.

義務がある/ない - describes such duties' being put on or waived from someone or a group

> かれは兵役の義務がある He has to serve his country.
>   かれは兵役の義務がない He is exempted from military service.

恩がある/ない - <strike>not a valid expression</strike> see comments

Comment: Great answer but 義理 in Japanese examples under the 人情がある/ない section seems to be wrong copy-and-paste. Also, we do say AにB(の)恩がある in the way of "owe B to A" in English.

Comment: @broccoliforest I was making examples based on かれは(X)がある form, and thought かれは恩がある is not valid. But you're right. It is perfectly legitimate to say かれはかのじょに恩がある when she did a favor of him and he owes to her.